# Trim strings of ServiceStack model

Tags: c#, string, servicestack

Is there a way to "automatically" trim strings of a ServiceStack model based on [StringLength()] attribute before it insert/update them in the DB?

I'm getting an error because the strings I'm trying to import from an external service are too long and my model is pretty big and have different string lengths... it would be expensive in terms of time trimming each string type in it manually.

Comment: What is the problem? You do not know how to truncate a string in c#? You do not know how to get the value of `StringLength`? What is that, you have a problem with?

Answer (score 1):

You can trim string properties using [OrmLite's String Filter](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite#string-filter):

```
OrmLiteConfig.StringFilter = s => s.TrimEnd();

db.Insert(new Poco { Name = "Value with trailing   " });
db.Select<Poco>().First().Name // "Value with trailing"
```

Comment: I'm sorry mythz, with "trim" I would intend "truncate" the extra-length of my strings...